# How to order the content of a set of files based on one file with Python

Tags: python, arrays, string

I'm stuck in a problem regarding strings order inside 3 text files. Here below and example:

`file_A.txt`

```
ID    value
AAA   1
BBB   2
CCC   3
```

`file_B.txt`

```
ID    value
BBB   2
AAA   1
CCC   3
```

`file_C.txt`

```
ID    value
CCC   3
AAA   1
BBB   2
```

As you can see, all the 3 files contain strings and these strings are the same for each file but in different order.
I'd like to use the `fileA.txt` strings order as footprint for the other files in order to modify `fileB.txt` and `fileC.txt` like this:

`file_A.txt`

```
ID    value
AAA   1
BBB   2
CCC   3
```

`file_B.txt`

```
ID    value
AAA   1
BBB   2
CCC   3
```

`file_C.txt`

```
ID    value
AAA   1
BBB   2
CCC   3
```

Thanks for tips and help.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and where exactly you got stuck/faced issues.

Comment: Read file A. Keep the strings in wanted order in a list (let's say `list_A`). Read B/C, use sort with `key=lambda row: list_A.index(row['ID'])` (`row['ID']` is assuming a row is a dict, modify for your model) to sort based on index in A, save.

Comment: As a general tip, keep in mind that what your files contain is "just" some data, so really your problem has three steps: reading and parsing the files, manipulating the data contained in the files (in language-native format independent of the file format, such as a Python list of lists, dicts, etc.), then writing the resulting data back out to your file format.

Comment: If you want to avoid getting naive answers such as copying fille_A.txt over the others, your samples should contain data that preclude sorting the other files independently.  It would also help identifying the part of the lines that you consider to be the sorting key.

Comment: Thanks for comment, you've been really helpful and kind. @h4z3 I followed your tip, really thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given these files:

```
$ head *.txt
==> file_a.txt <==
ID    value
AAA   1
CCC   3
BBB   2

==> file_b.txt <==
ID    value
BBB   2
AAA   1
CCC   3

==> file_c.txt <==
ID    value
CCC   3
AAA   1
BBB   2
```

You could do something like this:

```
from pathlib import Path 

p=Path(path_to_files)
id_file=Path('path_to_files/file_a.txt')

# create an index from file_a:
with open(id_file) as f:
    next(f)
    idx={line.split()[0]:i for i, line in enumerate(f)}

# for the other files, use that index to sort
for fn in p.glob('file_[bc].txt'):  # glob could be 'file_[!a].txt' too
    with open(fn, 'r+') as f:
        dat=f.readlines()
        f.seek(0)
        for line in [dat[0]]+sorted(dat[1:], 
                             key=lambda l: idx.get(l.split()[0],0)):
            f.write(line)
```

Result:

```
$ head *.txt
==> file_a.txt <==
ID    value
AAA   1
CCC   3
BBB   2

==> file_b.txt <==
ID    value
AAA   1
CCC   3
BBB   2

==> file_c.txt <==
ID    value
AAA   1
CCC   3
BBB   2
```

Comment: Ok I got an issue: 
`for line in [dat[0]]+sorted(dat[1:],key=lambda l: idx.get(l.split()[0], 0)):
IndexError: list index out of range`
(when I tried it yesterday this error was not present)

Comment: Likely either `dat` is an empty list (which means that your file has no content) or there is an empty line in your file which then is passed as `l` to `.split()`. Empty line or empty file. Test for those.